# Transform a string into a list of substrings describing sequences

Tags: string, list, haskell, split, sequence

I am trying to split a string into a list of sequences that are substrings of this string. It's a bit hard to explain but I will give you an example so you can understand what I am looking for.

From this string `"123456789"`, I would like to obtain a list like so:

`["123", "234, "345, ..., "789", "891", "912"]`

At the moment, I only have a function that splits a string into a list of `n` parts of this string:

```
splitList :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitList _ [] = []
splitList n xs = as : splitList n bs
    where (as,bs) = splitAt n xs
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a combination of `take` and `drop`, with a list comprehension:

```
splitList :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitList n xs = [take n $ drop i $ xs ++ xs | i <- [0..(length xs - 1)]]
```

(the `xs ++ xs` is only there to get the "cycling" affect, it could be tuned to only add on the first (n-1) elements but I believe Haskell's laziness should mean there is no efficiency loss in doing it this way)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is not doing a complete "circle" ("891", "912" not in the list) but I will try to fix this. Thanks again and have a good day :)

Comment: oops, that's because I only noticed the "cycle" late on, and updated the list it was taking from, but not the indices in the comprehension. I'll do that now. [EDIT: done]

Comment: I am not a huge fan of this approach. I would instead try to adapt `take n <$> tails xs` so that the shortest lists at the very end do not show up. This could also avoid the quadratic complexity wrt `length xs`, which the approach above has.

Comment: An edge case to consider: what if `n > 2*length xs`?

Comment: You're right, this won't behave correctly when `n` gets too large (in fact `n > length xs` is enough to mess it up as far as I can see). I confess I just hurriedly wrote up the first thing that popped into my head without thinking it through fully. It's pointless me adding more complexity to try to salvage this, given that you and Will have added better answers - but I'll leave this here because I think there is some value in showing a "naive" solution which works in most situations, as well as the valuable comments pointing out the flaws.

Comment: @RobinZigmond very true, about providing the counterpoint. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
import Data.List
splitList n xs = zipWith const chunks xs where
    chunks = map (take n) . tails . cycle $ xs
```

This should have complexity O(m*n), where m is the length of xs and n is the size of each chunk; naively it seems as though it should be hard to do better than that, since that's the size of the output. It also neatly handles a number of awkward edge cases, including working sensibly on infinite list inputs.

If you haven't seen the `zipWith const` trick before, it's definitely one worth adding to your arsenal. It lets you do roughly the same thing as `take (length xs) ys`, but without actually computing `length xs` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `zipWith const`, I must confess I was staring at that thinking "isn't `zipWith const xs ys` the same as `xs`?" before I saw your explanation and light slowly dawned :)

Answer (score 1):

```
splitList :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitList n xs = zipWith const (map (take n) . tails . cycle $ xs) xs

-- splitList n = zipWith const =<< map (take n) . tails . cycle

-- splitList n = map (take n) . tails . cycle >>= zipWith const
```

does the job, and also works on infinite input, i.e. is properly lazy.

`zipWith const` is used instead of `length` and `take`, counting in list elements instead of numbers.

The pointfree variants are even readable / illuminating somewhat as to what is going on here.

(forgot to mention, `tails` are from `Data.List`).

Comment: I had it all typed out already. :) decided to post it anyway, for the pointfree.  :)